# ¿Por qué Twilio rechaza mi template para una notificación de WhatsApp?

Tags: aplicación-web, whatsapp, twilio

Estoy tratando de crear un template de mensaje en Twilio para WhatsApp, El template es para notificar al usuario que su cita a quedado agendada. Como categoría escogo **utility**, ya que tengo entendido que es para notificaciones, sin embargo me rechazan el template al instante.
El nombre que le doy al template es: **notificacion_cita**.
El template es el siguiente: *Tu cita para la clase de {{1}} el {{2}} de {{3}} a las {{4}} ha quedado agendada.¡Nos vemos pronto!*
Me rechazan el template de forma inmediata y como error aparece que el contenido del template no tiene un formato válido.